# Getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : when reading jsonp response

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, jsonp

I am working on a piece of code where the user clicks on a button to make a call and the status of the call is displayed to him/her.

Everything is working fine and the calls are being made too, but the server which sends the json response is on another domain and I have no control over its response. I therefore used `jsonp` to get the response, but no matter what i did, i keep getting the error of *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token*.

I am attaching my code. please help as this is a live project and I am badly stuck in it. I need a response to be alerted with the message received by the server. the message received by the server in case of success is `{"success": {"status": "success", "message": "Call successfully placed"}}` and in case of error is `{"error": {"message": "Invalid API Key"}}`. I just need to display the message part.

my code:

```
function makecall() {
    document.getElementById('<%=click2call_submitbtn.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
    var agentNum = document.getElementById('<%=lblCallFrom.ClientID%>').innerHTML;
    var custNum = "+91";
    custNum = custNum + document.getElementById('<%=txtNotoCall.ClientID%>').value;
    document.getElementById('<%=lblCallStatus.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "Calling...";
    if (validatePhone(agentNum) && validatePhone(custNum)) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.knowlarity.com/vr/api/click2call/?api_key=9e69eab0-1ec7-11e3-866c-16829204aaa4&amp;agent_number=agent_number_variable&amp;phone_number=Caller_number_variable&amp;sr_number=%2B918881692001&amp;response_format=json'.replace('Caller_number_variable', custNum.replace('+', '%2B')).replace('agent_number_variable', agentNum.replace('+', '%2B')),
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (res) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(res));
            },
            error: function (res) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(res));
            }
        });

    } else {
        document.getElementById('<%=lblCallStatus.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "Num. should be a valid 10 digit mobile no.";
        document.getElementById('<%=click2call_submitbtn.ClientID%>').disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you getting back from the remote server, can you use fiddler and look for the response so see what its returning and if its in the expected format. Also why are you URl Encoding the &amp; between Query parameters

Comment: the response in alert that i am getting is {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"load"} and the console in Chrome is giving the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : . The URI encoding of &amp is because its the same i received from the server company. if I click on the www.knowlarity.com/:1 link shown in the console along with this error i get the text of success {"success": {"status": "success", "message": "Call successfully placed"}}.

Comment: Also when I tested the url in JSONLint validator is gave the output as a valid JSON. the output was {
    "success": {
        "status": "success",
        "message": "Call successfully placed"
    }
}

Comment: I used stringily(res) because I wanted to see what the complete output in string format was. if i used it as an object it was giving error of undefined. I will also do the splitting test which you suggested and will post back the result. thank you for taking out time.

Comment: I tried all the optioned mentioned by you and got the following responses. The console.log(res) gives error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
The var json = JSON.stringify(res);
   console.log(json);
gives the following error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : 

The var json = JSON.stringify(res);
alert(json);
gives the following error
{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"load"} and the console in Chrome is giving the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Also success: is never being called. only error: is called each time. but on clicking on the link along with the error in the console window i get the success response : {"success": {"status": "success", "message": "Call successfully placed"}}

Comment: The Developer tool window is showing the following data in the header section - Request URL:http://www.knowlarity.com/vr/api/click2call/?api_key=9e69eab0-1ec7-11e3-866c-12314104aaa4&amp;agent_number=%2B919897909999&amp;phone_number=%2B919997333227&amp;sr_number=%2B918881692001&amp;response_format=json&callback=jQuery20306715642381459475_1385039353412&_=1385039353413
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Comment: The Request Headers Show Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:www.knowlarity.com
Referer:http://localhost:55125/calldialler.aspx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36

Comment: Query String Parameters Show api_key:9e69eab0-1ec7-11e3-866c-12314104aaa4
amp;agent_number:%2B919897909999
amp;phone_number:%2B919997333227
amp;sr_number:%2B918881692001
amp;response_format:json
callback:jQuery20306715642381459475_1385039353412
_:1385039353413

Comment: Response Headers Show Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 21 Nov 2013 13:09:24 GMT
Server:nginx/1.1.19
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Cookie

Comment: I just don't know whats messing up. can you help now

Comment: What does the following mean in the header callback:jQuery203027668890985660255_1385039977472
_:1385039977473 could the problem me because of some problem in handling callback or conversion of JSON to JSONP?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this as an absolute minimum where you can pass in valid hard wired values for the numbers:

```
var url = 'http://ip.jsontest.com/ ';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (res) {

        if (res != undefined) console.log(res);
    },
    error: function (res) {

        if (res != undefined) console.log(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: I replaced my code with the one you send, but the same error. console in Developer tool says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : , the Network Tab shows the url http://www.knowlarity.com/vr/api/click2call/?api_key=9e69eab0-1ec7-11e3-866c-12314104aaa4&agent_number=%2B919897909999&phone_number=%2B919997333227&sr_number=%2B918881692001&response_format=json&callback=jQuery203011996779055334628_1385041995607&_=1385041995608 with Method GET and status 200 OK, the Header section is fine, the preview shows success: {status:success, message:Call successfully placed} & response too shows success

Comment: BUT despite all the above the error still exists and success section is never reached...

Comment: I suspect that the server where i am sending the request does not support JSONP. what do i do in such a case.?

Comment: I've updated the test URL to call a server the definitely returns a JSON object. It should be your IP address - Can you try that - on its own the code should work. If you are still having issues they are in your code somewhere and you will need to hunt them down. If this comes back OK then your server does not return JSON data  an you can simply remove the dataType: 'jsonp' and just make a normal get request